# NetSuite: How do you delete products from a category?

Tags: netsuite

Rookie NS question. I've got 1,000+ products in a category. I just created sub-categories and segmented the products better, so now all I want to do is remove the 1,000 products from the root category. How do I do that without having to do it one-at-a-time? Do I need to do a mass update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding you correctly, you've already added the products to their respective sub-categories and there's just unwanted copies of the bulk of them in the root category. Usually you'd have to delete them manually.

A shortcut:

- Make a temporary category
- Put the subcategories under that temp category
- Delete the root category. Deleting a root category will delete it's subcategories, so this is why your subcategories need to be under a different category before deleting the root.
- Recreate the root category and it'll be a clean slate for you to work with. You can then simply add the subcategories back to it and delete the temp category.

Comment: This makes sense. Do you need to recreate the root category (step 4)? Why not just rename the temp root category after you delete the original?

Comment: You are 100% correct. That's the beauty of networking. If you go that route, be sure to change the "url component" back to what the original category was. Otherwise any links from other pages to the root will break because it will be changed from example.com/root to example.com/tempcat it's a pain fixing all the links, especially if there are external sites linking to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar circumstance. I simply did a CSV update for Import Type: Website and Record Type: Site Category.
My CSV file had two columns, one for the internal id of the web category and one item with the value of the internal id of the item (Any random item).
Simply do the import, as an update, but the real trick is to select Update and Advanced Options below OVERWRITE SUBLISTS (tick).

In the field matching you map the internal id of the Site Category to the internal id field.
In the Site Category Presentation Items below, expand out and map the internal id of the item to item, ensuring you select internal id as the mapping option if you are in fact using this (option of Names are of course fine but I prefer always to use the Internal ID option which never changes).
Lastly select Type field for mapping and choose Item as a Default.
Example of this mapping below.

Category internal id **maps to** Site Category : Internal ID

Item internal id **maps to** Site Category Presentation Items 1 : Item
Item **maps to** Site Category Presentation Items 1 : Type

With the overwrite sublist selected, all the items will be removed and you will end up with just the one item in the Web Category, which you can then quickly delete if you want it completely empty.